# Passing data between 2 different tabs [Chrome extension]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I have my (content-script) js file that I need to transfer data from there to
another tab that has the URL of let's say [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
And I did try the sendMessage and all of those functions
but I can't combine them with the change of the URL(after I change
the URL the data just disappeared or I'm getting some kind of closed port error)

Comment: Send all data to the background script, then the background script will send it to the second tab. Alternatively, use `chrome.storage`.

Answer (score -1):

You can research about websocket to implement that feature. If you are using Javascript, I suggest socketIO for this.

Comment: I don't think i can do that because the site www.google.com doesn't allow web requests that's what I heard something like that. Plus i really think there is some kind of method i can use using chrome's API.